# Verify that a Value Exists using on BNF Javacc

Tags: java, parsing, production, bnf, javacc

If I was to parse this using BNF syntax only in Java CC.

```
correctAnswer "Afternoon"
wrongAnswer "Morning"
wrongAnswer "Evening"
```

Is there a way to check that at least one correct answer exists when parsing this using only BNF Syntax - No Java code at all.

So if we had this

```
wrongAnswer "Morning"
wrongAnswer "Evening"
```

Javacc would throw a parser exception as it's invalid format.

Any help would be great as I know how to do this in Java but lost for only BNF/JavaCC syntax.

So what would I need in my production to make this throw a parser exception - No java code!!!!!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
void answers() : {}
{
    (wrong())* correct() (wrong() | correct() )*
}
void wrong() : {}
{
    <WRONG_ANSWER> <STRING>
}
void correct() : {}
{
    <CORRECT_ANSWER> <STRING>
}
```